# Looping arrays using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
char ch[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
char* p = ch;
while(*p){
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    ++p;
}
```

This prints the elements of array + garbage but,

```
int ch[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int* p = ch;
while(*p){
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    ++p;
}
```

This prints just the elements of array no garbage.

I am just a beginner to c++ and i am failing to figure out the reason behind such behaviour.

Need some help with this.

Comment: Is this the complete code? I am missing some kind of p++ or ++p.

Comment: edited just now sry for that.

Comment: using arrays you should always remember its size. `while` loop with such statement will likely produce access violation exception at some point

Comment: You are running out of bound of your array in both example. This leads to UB and you may or may not get garbage. The program may or may not crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while (*p) {` continues until it hits a value of 0. In neither case have you ensured that there is a 0 terminating your arrays and it's just luck that one worked whilst the other didn't.

Comment: so if i recompile the code with the integer array over and over it should also print garbage at some point of time right?

Comment: Possibly, but not necessarily. However, you have little to no guarantee that your results would be the same as someone else's who ran your code on another computer.

Comment: @AneeshDandime: Running the same code on the same computer repeatedly often leads to it being run in the same chunk of memory and getting the same arbitrary bits in that memory and so you may find it fairly reproducible but if you run it on different days and different computers you should see that fairly soon.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of a defined end to your string you will continue to iterate beyond the intended array of characters, which will output data held within adjacent memory. Character strings are typically set up in c/c++ to terminate by null character ('\0') which allows the array to iterate until *p=='\0'.

If you add an element to the array, set the last element to '\0', and set the while loop to run until *p=='\0', you should achieve the desired output.

This will prevent the loop from overrunning your intended bounds and is a good practice in software security in addition to being functionally important, as outputting additional memory can sometimes be exploited in applications.